# Useradd Default Groups in 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, users, useradd

I'm working on building some new servers with 22.04. I use Ansible to create users, and noticed that when creating a new user, for example "test", the user's default group is now the "users" group. On 20.04, a user "test" would automatically create a group named "test". It looks like Ansible's user module is just using the "useradd" command. In 20.04, if I run `useradd test`, `test` would be in the `test` group. If I run it on 22.04, `test` is in the `users` group.
Is there a way for me to change the behavior of `useradd` to behave more like 20.04 in 22.04?

Comment: Do the two systems have different values of `USERGROUPS_ENAB` in their /etc/login.defs files?

Comment: It appears that its set to "yes" on the 20.04 system, and "no" on the 22.04 system. Sounds like that might be the cause

Comment: ... indeed, see `man useradd`